# What species is Chinese dried mushrooms (冬菇)?

Tags: chinese-cuisine

I don't speak any Chinese, but I asked some Hong Kong vendors and they wrote down "冬菇" for me. Some websites call these [Shiitake Mushrooms](https://en.christinesrecipes.com/2010/12/braised-shiitake-mushrooms-in-oyster.html), but is this correct? I know they're dried, but they still don't look like Shiitake to me.

[image]

Are these really the same species as Shiitake Mushrooms in American supermarkets?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[冬菇](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiitake) are indeed *Lentinula edodes* or shiitake mushrooms.

Note that mushrooms can vary a bit in color depending on where the were grown and dehydrating will also change them.